# Server return string in a new page frame

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage, session-cookies

How can I get hold of a string that gets displayed in a new page when user logs in? When user logs in the server returns session id and name that is a string. I have to split that string into two parts, session id and name of person logged in. I will only store **session id** in `localStorage` as this is a **phonegap** app

The return string is in this format *`927EEC302B5643D7A04EA7ADE8D48873|logginuser`**
So I will have to split session= "927EEC302B5643D7A04EA7ADE8D48873";
logginuser = "display name";

I am a newbie to `phonegap`; thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: so `var parts = str.split("|");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sessionId = '927EEC302B5643D7A04EA7ADE8D48873|logginuser';
var values = sessionId .split('|');
```

Comment: The value of the session id changes is does not stay the same when user login.

Comment: @JayStar Just and example, you should put the session id value in a var first ;-) Code updated

Comment: Ops sorry about that. I see now. Let me try it. i will mark the answer if it works.

Comment: Still not winning

Comment: `var stringFromServer= '38B0B73945F14C958DE0DCBD4DB66C55|logginuser|'.split('|');
        var sessionId = stringFromServer[0];
        var logginuser= stringFromServer[1];`
This did the trick.

Comment: @JayStar Sorry, I supposed you knew that split() returns an array.

Comment: thanks. Now the problem lies in getting that string. When i put password and email correct ones ofcourse. Hit the submit button. The server return the string on a new  page. When i test on a browser. 'https://www.example.com/login?/user@example.com|userpassword'. String is displayed. Now i go to the app. Login with same details. The page that display the string is now within my login page as a frame. M a newbie on this phonegap thing. Sorry for too much questions. How can i overcome this problem. The session id will tell if the user is loggedin or not which i will save in localStorage.

Comment: @JayStar Use JQuery or XPath to get the value from the iframe.

Comment: I have checked the `attr()` method of JQuery seems it will help on achieving this. The work around here will be to check inputs from user of which i do, if all is correct let the user submit. Sever return string if user exist, fetch the string in the iframe, split it and server it in localStorage than take user to home page. Can i do all this in my login function?